# Struts 2 : How to access to attributes of a Model object declared in an Action class, from a JSP page?

Tags: jsp, model, struts2, attributes

When I try to change an attribute of an Action class from a JSP page i can do it by a form for example, but when I try to change the attributes of an object declared in the Action class i can't do it.

The Model class :

```
public class User { 
  private String name;  
  public User(){
    this.setName("Unknown");
  } 
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

The Action class :

```
public class UserAction{
  private User user;
  public String execute(){
    user = new User();
  }
  public User getUser(){
    return user;
  }
  public void setUser( User user ){
    this.user = user;
  }
}
```

The User class sets a value by defaut in the constructor to the attribute and I can access it :

```
<s:property value="user.name" />
```

But when I try to change it through a form then to print its value in the targeted page after the form, I still get the default values :

```
<s:form action="welcomeAction" >
  <s:textfield name="user.name" label="User name " />
</s:form>
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It's fine, I was having a problem in struts.xml

Answer (score 2):

The following line in your `execute()` method was likely the culprit:

```
user = new User();
```

Action methods are invoked after parameters are set, so the framework will construct your User object, set the parameters, and then invoke the action method (in this case `execute()`), which promptly reassigns the user variable to a brand new User object, complete with default settings.

This also explains why changing the struts.xml to call a different method than execute fixed the problem (note that your original struts.xml config was fine).

Answer (score 0):

I was having in struts.xml :

```
<action name="welcomeAction" class="helloworld.action.UserAction">
<result>/welcome.jsp</result>
</action>
```

So, i've created a method setUserFields in the Action class, which returns "done" :

```
<action name="welcomeAction" class="helloworld.action.UserAction" method="setUserFields">
<result name="done">/welcome.jsp</result>
</action>
```